# line 17, in <module> print(f'{a[str(x)]}: {str(n)[r-c]}')

Tags: python

```
# variaveis
a = {'0': 'Milhar', '1': 'Centena', '2': 'Dezena', '3': 'Unidade'}
x = int(0)

# Variaveis
while True:
    n = str(input('Digit a number: '))
    if n.isnumeric():
        n = int(n)
        break
    else:
        print('Apenas numeros')
if n >= 4:
    r = 4
else:
    r = int(len(n))
for c in range(0, r):
    print(f'{a[str(x)]}: {str(n)[r-c]}')
    x += 1`
```

Comment: é o Python  3 -------

Comment: Por favor, inclua um título e descreva o seu problema.

Comment: já ouviu falar de titulo?

Comment: como você espera que outras pessoas encontrem a solução para um problema semelhante ao seu? digitando **print(f'{a[str(x)]}: {str(n)[r-c]}')** na busca do site ou no google?

Comment: @Schilive A resposta resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitá-la? Veja o [tour] se não souber como faz. Isso ajudaria muito indicar que a solução foi útil para você. Também pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo (quando tiver 15 pontos).

Answer (score 3):

O código tem vários erros. Acho que é isto que deseja:

```
a = {'0': 'Milhar', '1': 'Centena', '2': 'Dezena', '3': 'Unidade'}
while True:
    n = input('Digit a number: ') #só pede a digitação
    if n.isnumeric(): #verifica se é composto apenas por dígitos
        break #sai do laço se for
    else:
        print('Apenas numeros') #avisa o erro
r = len(n) #pega a quantidade de dígitos
if r >= 4: #normaliza para o máximo de 4
    r = 4
for c in range(0, r): #anda dígito por dígito
    print(f'{n[c]}: {a[str(r - c - 1)]}') #imprime a posição de cada caractere digitado
    #depois imprime o nome da grandeza pegando do dicionário, o - 1 porque começa do 0
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/23LwO7). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/ycebjuiy-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Python/Algorithm/SemiHumanizeNumber.py).

Erros:

```
x = int(0) #não faz sentido

n = str(input('Digit a number: ')) #não faz sentido usar `str()` em `input()` já é string

n = int(n) #ainda não é a hora de converter

if n >= 4: #não faz sentido verificar se o número digitado é maior que 4

r = int(len(n)) #não precisa transformar em int o que já é um

print(f'{a[str(x)]}: {str(n)[r-c]}') #a sintaxe tem tantos erros que nem sei onde começar

x += 1` #não tem porque existir esta variável e tem um erro de sinaxe aí
```

Comment: Valeu, voce ajudou muito

Comment: Eu sei, eu descobri depois, mas valeu mesmo assim